# Image Saving I/O Using Python Efficiency & Speed

Tags: python, io

I'm new to Python(and haven't used file IO in a while), so please bear with me if I make a beginners mistake in anything I'm saying.

I have .bmp images of about 5 MB's each. I want to take the average of two images and save the average in another file directory. This company laptop is 8 GB RAM, 64 bit, processor is AMD A10-7300 Radeon R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G 1.9 GHz

I did just that, but now my intern manager wants me to make the saving process much faster(It takes about 2-3 minutes right now for 500 images). I'm using the function imageResult.save(currentSavePath,"bmp").

Here is the image saving code:

```
# function for file selection 2
def FileSelect2(self, event):
    dirDialog = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE);

    # user canceled file opening
    if dirDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        return

    # otherwise, proceed loading the file chosen by the user
    self.rootDir2 = dirDialog.GetPath()
    self.subdirArray2 = [];
            for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(self.rootDir2):
                for fname in fileList:
                    if os.path.splitext(fname)[1] == '.bmp':
                        self.subdirArray2.append(dirName+'\\'+fname)

    self.fileDisplay2.Clear()
    self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
    self.blocker = False
    self.fileDisplay2.AppendText(self.rootDir2)
# function for making sure the directory matches
def CheckIfFilesMatch(self):
    if(self.subdirArray1.__len__() != self.subdirArray2.__len__()):
        self.statusText.SetValue("please enter same amount of files")
            self.blocker = True
            self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        return False 
    for f in self.subdirArray1:
        if f.replace(self.rootDir1,self.rootDir2) not in self.subdirArray2:
            self.statusText.SetValue("This file: " + f + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
                self.blocker = True
                self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
                return False
        for f in self.subdirArray2:
        if f.replace(self.rootDir2,self.rootDir1) not in self.subdirArray1:
            self.statusText.SetValue("This file: " + f + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
                self.blocker = True
                self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
                return False
```

## function for averaging images

```
def Average(self, event):
    self.CheckIfFilesMatch()
    if self.blocker:
        return
    self.count = 0
    # save file
    saveDialog = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory(Your files will be saved in same file names under this):", style=wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT);
    # cancel
        if saveDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            # update status
            self.statusText.SetValue("Did not save")
    self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        # ok
        return

    else:
        savePath = saveDialog.GetPath()
        # start reading file
        for i in self.subdirArray1:
                postfix = i.replace(self.rootDir1, "")
                print postfix
                print i
                f = self.rootDir2+postfix
                if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(savePath+postfix)):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(savePath+postfix))
                currentSavePath = savePath+postfix
            try:
                # update status
                self.statusText.SetValue("Processing...")
                self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
                # try reading the files
                print "first path: "+i
                print "second path: "+f
                self.im1 = Image.open(i)
                self.im2 = Image.open(f)
                self.count += 1
                # convert to matrix
                self.mat1 = numpy.array(self.im1)
                self.mat2 = numpy.array(self.im2)
                # convert to uint16 for addition
                self.mat1 = self.mat1.astype('uint16')
                self.mat2 = self.mat2.astype('uint16')
                # get offset
                try:
                        self.offset = int(self.offsetCtrl.GetValue())
                except ValueError:
                        #throw error
                        self.statusText.SetValue("Error: please enter integer offset")
                        self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
                        return
                # add and convert back to image (with offset)
                self.result = (self.mat1 + self.mat2 + self.offset)/2
                self.result[self.result > 255] = 255
                # convert back to uint 8 for saving
                self.result = self.result.astype('uint8')
                self.imResult = Image.fromarray(self.result)
                # self.imResult = Image.blend(self.im1, self.im2, 1)
                    self.imResult.save(currentSavePath,"bmp")
                            # update status
                    self.statusText.SetValue("Saved image to " + currentSavePath)
                    self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
            except IOError:
                # throw error
                self.statusText.SetValue("Error: cannot read file : " + i + " or " + f)
                self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
    return
```

Is 2-3 minutes normal? Can it go faster? Should I decrease the resolution on the final image?

Comment: In your `CheckIfFilesMatch` method, is that a nested for-loop?

Comment: @Smac89 No it's not, that was some indentation bug when I copy pasted the text haha, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a codeReview answer. It seems that your image saving process is quite fast as observed by [Didier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31927505/2089675), so I will just propose some optimizations for the other process involved which is the `CheckIfFilesMatch` method. This piece of code which right now has complexity O(N<sup>2</sup>)

```
for f in self.subdirArray1:
    if f.replace(self.rootDir1,self.rootDir2) not in self.subdirArray2:
        self.statusText.SetValue("This file: " + f + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
        self.blocker = True
        self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        return False
for f in self.subdirArray2:
    if f.replace(self.rootDir2,self.rootDir1) not in self.subdirArray1:
        self.statusText.SetValue("This file: " + f + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
        self.blocker = True
        self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        return False
```

You can make it O(N) by creating a set from either `self.subdirArray1` or `self.subdirArray2`. Then the code will now look like:

```
def CheckIfFilesMatch(self):
    if(len(self.subdirArray1) != len(self.subdirArray2)):
        self.__FileMatchError("please enter same amount of files")
        return False

    tmp = set(self.subdirArray2)
    for f in self.subdirArray1:
        frev = f.replace(self.rootDir1,self.rootDir2);
        if frev not in tmp:
            self.__FileMatchError("This file: " + f + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
            return False
        tmp.discard(frev)
    if tmp:
        self.__FileMatchError("This file: " + tmp.pop() + " does not correspond to any file in parallel.")
        return False
    return True

def __FileMatchError(self, txt):
    self.statusText.SetValue(txt)
    self.blocker = True
    self.statusText.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the total IO workload it represents.

You have 500 images, 5 MB each, and you need to read two of them to write one. So you read 500*5*2 = 5 GB, and you write 2.5 GB on the disk.

Let's suppose it lasts 3 minutes. It means the I/O throughput is 27.7 MB/s in read mode and 13.8 MB/s in write mode. This result is not so bad for a classical rotational disk.

Now, if you have a SSD on this laptop, it means you are far from saturating the I/O bandwidth, and probably you could do better. For instance, you could try to parallelize the process (by introducing a pool of threads).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to speed up the computation using a GPU.  2-3 minutes for 500 images is not all that strange, for large image processing research dedicated servers are often used.

As for saving, the disk is the slow factor here. Use a dedicated stack for this purpose or change to SSD if you can.